# How to show icons in ActionBar overflow menu?

Tags: android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android

I want to display icon in addition to menu item title in overflow dropdown menu.

Is is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To show icons in Overflow menu in ActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar)

Comment: Refer @Kevin Grant's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar

Comment: see this: [how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar)

Answer (score 32):

put your menu with property  `android:showAsAction="always"` and in xml file of menu add sub menus under that your menu like this

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/log_out"
                android:title="logout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

this will show the icons in menus

Comment: Submenu icons are not shown in gingerbread. Working ok in 4.x

Comment: This is not appropriate for phones with a physical menu button.

Comment: This does not address items in the action overflow.

Comment: This would replace the overflow, you do NOT want the overflow.

Comment: This is in no way correct. It just adds a submenu. It does not display icons in overflow menu.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually an easy way to achieve it, since what you see is actually a TextView, so you set a span , for example:

```
final MenuItem menuItem=...
final ImageSpan imageSpan=new ImageSpan(this,R.drawable.ic_stat_app_icon);
final CharSequence title=" "+menuItem.getTitle();
final SpannableString spannableString=new SpannableString(title);
spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan,0,1,0);
menuItem.setTitle(spannableString);
```

This will put an icon at the beginning of the menu item, right before its original text.

Comment: This is the best solution and perhaps is the most easy solution. 
Icon is now visible left to the menu item.
But the text aligns to the bottom of the icon. How can we make it vertically center?

Comment: @SureshKumar You mean you want them both vertically centered? Hmmmm... Maybe you could create your own customized span, but then I don't know how well it will look on some devices... Perhaps there is a way that I'm not aware of for this. Since I don't handle it anymore, I would be happy in case you show what you've found, inc ase you find anything.

Comment: Works great. I just have to figure out how to set a certain size for the image. Anyway, best solution I found! Here have my gratitude!

Comment: @TobiasReich Have you found how to make it centered?

Comment: Actually I haven't really tried so far. But shouldn't you just change the gravity of the TextView?

Comment: @TobiasReich It's a menuItem. Sure it's a TextView too, but I'd assume there is a better way... Maybe one of those: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628258/align-text-around-imagespan-center-vertical http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406548/imagespan-alignment-in-textview

Answer (score 2):

Hate answers like this but I am not good enough to give a better answer.

The icon for the overflow items for menu is the submenu2 line "subMenu2Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);"
just replace ic_launcher with your icon file (in the res drawable directory of your program).
Hope you mean using ActionBarSherlock.

The line subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); is for the ActionBar icon for the Menu button at the top.

in response to "This is not possible by design"

Many thanks to Google for attempting to take over the world and letting us ride it's coat tails, BUT ... Google is too inconsistent to be grumpy over inconsistencies.
It would be nice if Google could make an example for EVERY "set" of APIs they offer. There are API references to code, but no example about how to put them together, A whole completely working example that can be run as an APK is all I want. I can trick it out from there. If they can take the time to write the APK how much harder would it be to code a little example on a standard template? For 30% of everything it's not much to ask for.
I had this same argument with Microsoft back in the day and it didn't happened then either. And thus and so you get stackoverflow. : )   Its a shame it takes some guy (rock on Jake Wharton) working on his own to do a better job with a backwards compatible Action bar than Google can come up with its ridiculous Action Bar Patch thingy.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

    SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Action Item");
    subMenu1.add("Help");
    subMenu1.add("About");

    MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
    subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    SubMenu subMenu2 = menu.addSubMenu("All Options");
    subMenu2.add("Help");
    subMenu2.add("About");

    MenuItem subMenu2Item = subMenu2.getItem();
    subMenu2Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu)
{
    if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
        if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
            try{
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                    "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            }
            catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "onMenuOpened", e);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

Reference : [How To show icons in Overflow menu in ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar)

Comment: This will break if you use proguard. Keeping MenuBuilder in your proguard config should work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have the same problem as me. So for me solution was easy if you are using AppCompat just dont use this property:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

instead use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option"
        android:title="@string/option"
        android:icon="@drawable/option"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

There is difference in aditional **xmlns:app** and **showAsAction** is property of **app**.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: You don't even understand the question, with showAsAction as `always`, the icon is always shown BUT it's like an action bar button, rather than in the menu item inside the dropped-down menu. Not sure why this received some up votes.

Comment: From other people who also do not understand the question.

Comment: @KingKing he got some upvotes not because this question, its because his answer solved other types of problems related "Action Bar" ....like me , i want to display the icons in appbar but items are going inside overflow menu ... and his answer saved my life .... i know this is not the place to put this answer but at least it helps some one ,,,, e.g. myself

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by design (at least in HC - and I'm developing on API 16 and getting no icons either). Google does not want us to do that.

For a bit of discussion on the topic, see related answer here:

- [Displaying icon for menu items of Action Bar in Honeycomb android 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216625/383414)

As one of the comments suggests, if you need the icons, consider using a dropdown menu, rather than the overflow menu.