# Aligning ImageSpan with Spanable String

Tags: android, android-layout

I know there are many questions of the same type available and I have tried so many solutions but all of them are not meeting my requirements.

My problem is that I have to add a dynamic line spacing between the text containing Spanable strings and Imagespan but when I add the line spacing the alignment of the text and image gets distorted.

I have tried almost all of the solutions available on Stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422921/3338287), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422921/3338287) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28361364/3338287) but all in vein.
I have attached screenshots

1. Screenshot before adding dynamic line spacing

[image: Screenshot before adding dynamic line spacing] 
 2. Screenshot after adding dynamic line spacing

[image: Screenshot after adding dynamic line spacing]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use "y" in onDraw method to find the baseline of text and then align the drawable to baseline of text view

```
public class VerticalImageSpan extends ImageSpan {



 public VerticalImageSpan(Drawable drawable) {
        super(drawable);
    }

    /**
     * update the text line height
     */
    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                       Paint.FontMetricsInt fontMetricsInt) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        Rect rect = drawable.getBounds();
        if (fontMetricsInt != null) {
            Paint.FontMetricsInt fmPaint = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
            int fontHeight = fmPaint.descent - fmPaint.ascent;
            int drHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
            int centerY = fmPaint.ascent + fontHeight / 2;

            fontMetricsInt.ascent = centerY - drHeight / 2;
            fontMetricsInt.top = fontMetricsInt.ascent;
            fontMetricsInt.bottom = centerY + drHeight / 2;
            fontMetricsInt.descent = fontMetricsInt.bottom;
        }
        return rect.right;
    }

    /**
     * see detail message in android.text.TextLine
     *
     * @param canvas the canvas, can be null if not rendering
     * @param text   the text to be draw
     * @param start  the text start position
     * @param end    the text end position
     * @param x      the edge of the replacement closest to the leading margin
     * @param top    the top of the line
     * @param y      the baseline
     * @param bottom the bottom of the line
     * @param paint  the work paint
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                     float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        canvas.save();
        Paint.FontMetricsInt fmPaint = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
        int fontHeight = fmPaint.descent - fmPaint.ascent;
        int centerY = y + fmPaint.descent - fontHeight / 2;
        int transY = centerY - (drawable.getBounds().bottom - drawable.getBounds().top) / 2;
        canvas.translate(x, transY);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```