# Android menu item not showing drawable

Tags: android, menu

Im using the `ActionBarActivity` on my activity and inflating the following menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:microecs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/description_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    microecs:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


<!--TODO: get a good logout icon-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_logoff"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_logout"
    android:title="@string/description_logoff"
    android:orderInCategory="2"

    microecs:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

The second menu item `drawable` that i want to appear as a `menu` and not in the action bar doesn't not appear in my **S4 (running 4.3)** and also on lower devices running **2.3.7**

Answer (score 3):

Just update your code with following code.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:microecs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/description_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    microecs:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


<!--TODO: get a good logout icon-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_logoff"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_logout"
    android:title="@string/description_logoff"
    android:orderInCategory="2"

    microecs:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Whenever you are using `never` then it dont place that item in the Action Bar.

For about menu refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by design. Overflow menus from the action bar don't show icons - that's just a design decision Google made.

You can check more, e.g. here: [Displaying icon for menu items of Action Bar in Honeycomb android 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216603/displaying-icon-for-menu-items-of-action-bar-in-honeycomb-android-3-0/5216625#5216625)