# Can't display an icon in the actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm trying to show a map icon downloaded from the official android developers source.

I did everything as it should, but the icon won't show.
Here is my xml file named `main_activity_bar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapIcon"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_map"
        android:title="@string/mapIconTitle"
        android:showAsAction="always"
     />

</menu>
```

Here is the main activity xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gs.testApp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

and this is what I have in the java class:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater actionMenue = getMenuInflater();
        actionMenue.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Everything seems to be fine, but the icon wont show on the emulator. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The minimum version is android 3.0

Why the icon is not showing? What Am I missing? I know that it is something really small, but I can't spot it.

Comment: click the 3 dot overflow menu icon to see the action bar icon. If there is nor  enough space it will be seen in the overflow menu

Comment: @Raghunandan when I click on the 3 dots I can see only the title `test` in my case. On the screenshot above it is already clicked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216603/displaying-icon-for-menu-items-of-action-bar-in-honeycomb-android-3-0/5216625#5216625. Quotng Romain Nurik "The behavior where icons are not displayed in the action bar's overflow menu is by design"

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I fixed it - in case that someone is facing the same issue.

I changed

`android:showAsAction="always"` to  `app:showAsAction="always"` and I also placed the icon order `android:orderInCategory="0"` and the auto res `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` so now my xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:id="@+id/mapIcon"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_map"
        android:title="@string/mapIconTitle"
        app:showAsAction="always"
     />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think an icon is shown in the overflow menu. Try changing your title to "t" or rotate the screen. See if the icon appears this way.