# Giving PopupMenu a shadow in API 21+

Tags: android, android-layout

This has been posted many times, but none of the existing solution appears to work with API 21+. The default popup's background color is exactly the same as the default background color for the layouts.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxiBd.png) is what it looks like (The popup is over a gridview but it has no obvious 'boundary' which looks a little off)

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpAxz.png) is ideal,i.e, with a proper material design shadow. There's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699482/styling-the-popup-menu-in-android-5-0) for accomplishing this with the toolbar popup menu. Not with a 'normal' PopupMenu.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320663/change-background-popupmenu-in-android) old question is trying to accomplish the same, however the given solution now no longer works:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/bgPopumMenu</item>
</style>
```

And neither does setting a custom context wrapper:

```
 Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.PopupMenu);
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, anchorView);
```

So, I'm unable to even change the background color of the popupmenu, let alone have a proper material design shadow.

How to give PopupMenu a shadow? Or how do I at least use a custom background drawable (using which I could put in a 9 patch shadow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate style for Lollipop+.
Create another resource: `res/values-v21/styles.xml`.
Add there Your popup style and specify needed elevation:

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:popupElevation">20dp</item>
</style>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Add popupMenu style to ur AppTheme:
    
        @style/PopupMenu

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
.............
</application>
```

PS: Answer taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231556/4315449)

Comment: If you'll see my question, you'll find I've already tried exactly that. It does not work (at least in API 21+)